# How can I specify an iterator over traits?

Tags: rust

I've been trying to make a websocket client, but one that has tons of options! I thought of using a builder style since the configuration can be stored in a nice way:

```
let client = Client::new()
    .options(5)
    .stuff(true)
    // now users can store the config before calling build
    .build();
```

I am having trouble creating a function that takes in a list of strings. Of course I have a few options:

```
fn strings(self, list: &[&str]) -> Self;
fn strings(self, list: Vec<String>) -> Self;
fn strings(self, list: &[&String]) -> Self;
// etc...
```

I would like to accept generously so I would like to accept `&String`, `&str`, and hopefully keys in a `HashMap` (since this might be used with a large routing table) so I thought I would accept an iterator over items that implement `Borrow<str>` like so:

```
fn strings<P, Sp>(self, P)
where P: Iterator<Item = &'p Sp>,
  Sp: Borrow<str> + 'p;
```

A full example is available [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=43eb09db15f9a314538a&version=stable).

This was great until I needed to add another optional list of strings (extensions) to the builder.

This meant that if I created a builder without specifying both lists of strings that the compiler would complain that it couldn't infer the type of the `Builder`, which makes sense. The only reason this is not OK is that both these fields are optional so the user might never know the type of a field it hasn't yet set.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to specify an iterator over traits? Then I wouldn't have to specify the type fully at compile time. Or maybe just a better way to do this entirely?

Comment: Your code here has a type parameter on the function, but your example code has it on the builder struct. These mean different things.

Comment: @Shepmaster yes I know I just wanted to keep my examples consistent.

Comment: *to keep my examples consistent* — but... your examples are **inconsistent**. One has a parameterized function, the other has a parameterized type. I must be missing something obvious...?

Comment: @Shepmaster yes your right that the last example is misleading, it would have been better to have all of the snippets be the struct definition.  I'm just talking about the types being stored, not the exact implementation of how they get stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pragmatic solution is to simply discard the concrete types of the types and introduce some indirection. We can `Box` the trait object and store that as a known type:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

struct Builder {
    strings: Option<Box<Iterator<Item = Box<Borrow<str>>>>>,
}

impl Builder {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Builder { strings: None }
    }

    fn strings<I>(mut self, iter: I) -> Self
        where I: IntoIterator + 'static,
              I::Item: Borrow<str> + 'static,
    {
        let i = iter.into_iter().map(|x| Box::new(x) as Box<Borrow<str>>);
        self.strings = Some(Box::new(i));
        self
    }

    fn build(self) -> String {
        match self.strings {
            Some(iter) => {
                let mut s = String::new();
                for i in iter {
                    s.push_str((*i).borrow());
                }
                s
            },
            None => format!("No strings here!"),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = 
        Builder::new()
        .strings(vec!["a", "b"])
        .build();
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

Here we convert the input iterator to a boxed iterator of boxed things that implement `Borrow`. We have to do some gyrations to convert the specific concrete type we have into a conceptually higher level type but that is still concrete.

---

This remainder doesn't directly answer your question about an iterator of traits, but it provides an alternate solution that I would use.

You have to pick between that might be a bit more optimal and have a worse user experience, or something that might be a bit suboptimal but a nicer user experience.

You are currently storing the iterator in the builder struct:

```
struct Builder
    where I: Iterator
{
    things: Option<I>,
}
```

This requires that the *concrete type* of `I` be known in order to instantiate a `Builder`. Specifically, the size of that type needs to be known in order to allocate enough space. There's nothing around this; if you want to store a generic type, you need to know what type it is.

For the same reasons, you cannot have this standalone statement:

```
let foo = None;
```

How much space needs to be allocated for `foo`? You cannot know until you know what type the `Some` might hold.

The way I would go would be to not add type parameters for the *struct*, but have them on the *function*. This means that the struct has to have a fixed type to store the values. In your example, a `String` is a good fit:

```
struct Builder {
    strings: Vec<String>,
}

impl Builder {
    fn strings<I>(mut self, iter: I) -> Self
        where I: IntoIterator,
              I::Item: Into<String>,
    {
        self.strings.extend(iter.into_iter().map(Into::into));
        self
    }
}
```

A `Vec` has very compact storage (it only takes 3 machine-sized values), and doesn't allocate any heap memory when it is empty. For that reason, I wouldn't wrap it in an `Option` unless you needed to tell 0 items from the absence of a provided value.

If you are just appending each value to one big string, you might as well do that in the `strings` method. That depends on your application.

You mention that you might be providing a large amount of data, but I'm not sure that holding the iterator until the `build` call will really help. You are going to pay the cost earlier or later.

If you are going to reuse the builder, then it depends on what is expensive. If iterating is expensive, then doing it once and reusing that for each `build` call will be more efficient. If holding onto the memory is expensive, then you don't want to have multiple builders *or* built items around concurrently. Since the builder will transfer ownership of the memory to the new item, there shouldn't be any waste here.

Comment: you're right that holding on the iterator won't help much. I was just worried about being wasteful, but you're right about the cons of holding on to an iterator like that. Also your example is much more concise than mine (using `I::Item`), that's pretty cool!

Comment: @MichaelEden finally answered how to do it.